# HP Elitebook x360 1040 G6 Intel AX200 wifi not found

Tags: wireless, intel

I am trying to get wifi working on my hp elitebook. I have tried copying the firmware files from here:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

To /lib/firmware without success.

I am currently running kernel 5.3.0-28-generic on ubuntu 18.04.1 so it should be supported.

Lspci shows the iwlwifi driver is loaded but wifi still does not show up.

```
6c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0088
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Demsg shows there is an error when trying to load the wifi driver:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   51.551480] iwlwifi 0000:6c:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   51.919499] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:6c:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Not sure what else to try here.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:6c:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0100000-e0103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enxe8d8d1adfc1a
       serial: e8:d8:d1:ad:fc:1a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.10 duplex=full ip=130.20.231.223 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s

lsusb
Bus 006 Device 005: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 006: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 0424:5807 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2109:0820 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 2109:8888 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 013: ID 03f0:0667 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 005 Device 010: ID 03f0:0567 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 005 Device 008: ID 03f0:0269 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 005 Device 012: ID 0451:ca01 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 011: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 009: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 005 Device 007: ID 095d:9205 Polycom, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0424:2807 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:2820 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b671 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00b7 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1050:0406 Yubico.com 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 11)
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dfc (rev 11)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 9def (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de8 (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de9 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de0 (rev 11)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de3 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbc (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db0 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db4 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d84 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 11)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
37:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
38:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
39:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
39:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge DD 2018] (rev 06)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
6c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
6d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981

$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```